# Return output data from gocron task

Tags: go

I use `gocron` as my scheduler, which run anonymous function:

```
j := Job{}
j.ClientID = clientid
j.Topic = topic
j.Range = range
j.Interval = interval
j.Task = func(s string, t string){
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(t)
    Query_by_limit(s, t)// <-- data wanted
}

gocron.Every(j.Interval).Seconds().Do(j.Task, j.Topic, j.Range)
gocron.Start()
```

How can I capture the data from `Query_by_limit()` everytime it arrived and send it for processing?

Comment: Use channels and add a receiver for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than a few factors that could impact the solution you want to go with. Here are the questions that need answers before thinking about how to proceed.

- How does your `gocron` library work? Does it execute jobs concurrently, while maintaining the scheduled order of the jobs that need to be executed? Or do all of the scheduled jobs get executed in the same thread/goroutine?
- Do you care about in which order the retrieved data gets processed? Does it need to be processed in the order in which is retrieved?
- Do you want to process the data immediately or does that also happens within a separate scheduled job?
- Does data processing take more or less time than the duration of the interval between two scheduled jobs?

Here is a solution with assumptions that the scheduler is not executing tasks concurrently (some of the `gocron` libraries work in this way), data processing never takes more than the duration of the job's waiting interval, and that data needs to be processed in the order in which is retrieved.

```
queryJob := Job{}
dataCh := make(chan interface{}) 
done := make(chan bool)
queryJob.ClientID = clientid
queryJob.Topic = topic
queryJob.Range = range
queryJob.Interval = interval
queryJob.Task = func(s string, t string, dataCh chan<- interface{}){
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(t)
    data, err := Query_by_limit(s, t)
    if err != nil {
      //handle error
    }
    dataCh <- data //if dataCh is an unbuffered channel, the job blocks here until the data is read in the data processing goroutine
    
}

//data processing goroutine
go func() {
  for data := range dataCh {
    //process data
  }
  done <-true
}()

gocron.Every(j.Interval).Seconds().Do(j.Task, j.Topic, j.Range, dataCh)
gocron.Start()
//when scheduler exits, you can close dataCh and give it a chance to be emptied
close(dataCh)
<-done
```

If you don't want to block your job until the data is read in the data processing goroutine, you can make the `dataCh` channel to be a buffered channel.

The solution gets way more complex if the data processing takes longer than the waiting interval of your scheduled job, and you still want to maintain the order of the data that needs to be processed. The same goes if you want to process the data in a different scheduled job. In these cases, I would recommend trying out solutions with queues that store and maintain the order of the data in them, as well as implementing draining the queues and processing all of the data before your program exits.